# Define a function that expects a number n and an array a and returns an array with size n, whereby the result contains the occurences of number i in a

Tags: ruby

Example: the function

```
frequencies (3,[0,1,1,0,1,1]) should return [2,4,0]
```

Here's what I have:

```
def minPosFrom (a, pos)
  min = a[pos]
  minPos = pos
  for i in pos+1 .. a.size-1 do
    if a[i] < min
      then minPos =i
      min = a[i]
    end
  end
  return minPos
end

def swap!(a,i,j)
  dummy = a[i]
  a[i] = a[j]
  a[j] = dummy
end

def minSort!(a)
  for i in 0 .. a.size-2 do
    pos = minPosFrom(a,i)
    swap!(a,i,pos)
  end
  return a
end


def frequencies(a)
  minSort!(a)
  b=1
  i=0
  while a[i]==a[i+1] do
    b=b+1
    i=i+1
    return (b)
  end
end
```

Now

```
p(frequencies([0,1,1,0,1,1]))
```

gives me a `2` for the two leading zeros. Which is nice. But I want the whole thing to continue and to get also a `4` for the four following ones, so `[2,4]`. Actually I'll need `[2,4,0]` if `n=3`, but I haven't defined the `n` yet, but I think this won't be hard to do once I get the program to give me the number of repeating numbers in an array...

Expect to see: p(frequencies([0,1,1,0,1,1])) -> [2,4,0]
actually see: p(frequencies([0,1,1,0,1,1])) -> [2]
tried: various loops and other functions.

Comment: That's great and all, but what is your question? Please edit your question and describe exactly what you would expect to see, what you actually see, why you think that differs from your expectation and preferably what you have already tried to solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def frequencies(n, array)
  n.times.map { |num| array.count(num) }
end
```

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag looks a bit cryptic for people new to ruby

Comment: That was short. :D I don't know any of these commands, but I'll try to work with that. Thanks.

Comment: read documentation for all of this methods: `times`, `map`, `Array#count`

Comment: @user3071205, you should select this as the answer. A thing of beauty it is, and a nice demonstration of Ruby magic.